# Grunt don't concatenate css and jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gruntjs, concatenation

Grunt should concatenate both my css and jQuery so I used this code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {


    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        watch: {
            jquery: {
                files: ['jquerytest/**/*.js'],
                tasks: ['concat:js']
            },
            css: {
                files: ['css/*.css'],
                tasks: ['concat:css3']
            },
            scss:{
                files: ['csstest/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass:dist']
            }
        },

        concat: {
            js : {
                options: {
                    separator: ',\n',
                    banner: 'jQuery.fn.extend({',
                    footer: '});'
                },
                files: {
                    src: ['jquerytest/general/MyFunJqueryLibrary.js', 'jquerytest/general/MySetJqueryLibrary.js'],
                    dest: 'jquery/MyJqueryLibrary.js'
                },
            },
            css3 : {
                options: {
                    separator: '\n'
                },
                files: {
                    src: ['css/MyLibraryCss.css', 'css/MyLibraryScss.css'],
                    dest: 'css/css.css'
                },
            },
        },

        compass: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    sassDir: 'csstest',
                    cssDir: 'css'
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // Default task(s).
    grunt.registerTask('concatjs', ['concat:dist1', 'concat:dist2']);
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

When running the `watch` task I get this message:

```
File "css\MyLibraryCss.css" changed.
Running "concat:css3" (concat) task
```

but nothing happens. However, when using the jQuery concat task it works, the problem happens only when I use two tasks inside concat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with registering task. The task 'concat:dist1' and 'concat:dist2' does not exists. Instead you have to write 'concat:js' and 'concat:css3'.

Comment: thank you for answering but it's just that i forgot to deleted after that i tried to solve the problem with a registred task (please correct me if i'm wrong)

Comment: I think you there is mistake in  concatenation task. If you use 'files' , you don't need to use 'src' and 'dest'. You can write the concat task in this way,

 css3 : {
                options: {
                    separator: '\n'
                },
               
                 src: ['css/MyLibraryCss.css', 'css/MyLibraryScss.css'],
                 dest: 'css/css.css'
              
            } 

You can check documentation here https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat